# How to quickly find out the entry requirements to country X for a citizen of country Y?

Tags: visas, international-travel, visas-on-arrival, visa-free-entry, visa-runs

For example: I'm an Irish citizen and I want to know if I need a visa for Kyrgyzstan... or I'm American and I want to know what countries I can enter visa free in South America... etc.

I've often found it difficult to quickly find this sort of information online. At best a Google search finds an embassy webpage which you then have to trawl through it to get the actual answer to your question. Are there better approaches out there?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Timatic is generally considered the definitive reference for Visas. It's what most travel agents use when booking tickets, and what most airlines use when verifying you have the correct visa before boarding.

In general [Timatic](http://www.iata.org/publications/Pages/timaticweb-travel-requirements.aspx) isn't free, however a number of websites do allow free access to it, such as [Star Alliance](http://www.staralliance.com/en/services/visa-and-health/) and [Gulf Air](http://www.gulfair.com/English/info/prepare/Pages/VisaInformation.aspx). You can use either of these websites to check the requirements not only for your destination, but also any transit points.

Comment: That's a great service for getting a general yes/no on the visa question, or for transit passengers, etc.. Thanks for the links!

Answer (score 4):

I've always found http://www.projectvisa.com/ to be a very helpful resource as it gives you a really quick way to check visa requirements and then you can verify it against one of the links (typically to the countries Foreign Affairs website). While travelling I've noticed that few people seem to know about this site because it pretty much never shows up on a Google search, so I figured it would be handy to share this with the Travel Stack Exchange community.

Comment: Just curious, are you affiliated with the site?

Comment: Not at all. I stumbled across it a few years ago and found it very useful over the last year travelling around Asia. When I was chatting with other backpackers on the road I realised that no-one else had heard of it, so here seemed like a good place to spread the word.

Comment: One warning about this site - it seems to be very focused on Tourism, and does not give any information for business travelers.  The details given for a few countries I checked were wrong for business visitors.