# Do I require airport transit visa at Frankfurt?

Tags: visas, schengen, transit, indian-citizens

I am flying from Mumbiai to Montego Bay via Dubai and Frankfurt as my final destination. Do i require airport transit visa at Frankfurt. i will be having invitation letter from husband and  even visa from Montego Bay.

Comment: This is NOT a duplicate of that question. The rules are different for transiting more than one Schengen country (as in that question) compared to transiting only a single Schengen country (as here)

Comment: It is only a duplicate of http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/19137/do-i-need-an-airport-transit-visa-through-switzerland-schengen-if-i-have-no-sc

Comment: @Doc I hesitated before voting to close. On the one hand, you are obviously right but on the other hand the other question also implicitly covers this case and provides a relevant link. Maybe we need to make one of them the canonical “one stop in Schengen” question.

Answer (score 4):

According to TIMATIC, you do not need a visa if you are

> holding onward tickets in transit through
>   Cologne/Bonn (CGN), Frankfurt (FRA), Munich (MUC), Hamburg (HAM),
>   Dusseldorf (DUS) or Berlin Tegel (TXL) **AND** meeting one of the
>   following conditions:
>
> - holding a valid visa issued by Bulgaria, Canada, Croatia,    Cyprus, Ireland (Rep.), Japan, Romania, USA or United    Kingdom;

If you hold a visa for any of these countries and your connection is less than 24 hours then you can transit Frankfurt without a visa.

If you do NOT hold a visa for any of these countries then you WILL require a transit visa for Frankfurt.

The Lufthansa website also [contains similar details](http://www.lufthansa.com/online/portal/lh/in/local?nodeid=3116855).

Answer (score 3):

According to the [Airport Transit in Germany](http://www.germany.info/Vertretung/usa/en/05__Legal/02__Directory__Services/01__Visa/__Transit__Visa.html) page, you likely **do** need a visa (assuming you are a national of India):

> Nationals of the following countries are required to be in possession of an airport transit visa when passing through the international transit area of airports in Germany:
>
> AFGHANISTAN, BANGLADESH, DEMOCRATIC REPUBLIC OF THE CONGO, ERITREA, ETHIOPIA, GHANA, INDIA, IRAN, IRAQ, JORDAN ** (please see below), LEBANON, MYANMAR, MALI, NIGERIA, PAKISTAN, SOMALIA, SRI LANKA, SUDAN, SOUTH SUDAN, SYRIA, TURKEY

There are exceptions to the above rule for holders of various USA visas and related documents, but if you're not travelling to or from the USA then those exceptions won't apply to you.

Comment: The OP most likely does not have a US visa or residence permit but technically the exception might apply even for a trip from Mumbai to Montego Bay.