# Transiting in a Schengen airport with a Romanian visa

Tags: visas, schengen, munich

I am an Indian traveling from Dubai to Sibiu (Romania). I am planning to travel with Lufthansa via Munich. Dubai to Munich and Munich to Sibiu flights are at terminal 2 in Munich. I don't have an Schengen visa and I have only Romanian visa. Is there any immigration problem to do this transit at Munich terminal 2?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Do I require airport transit visa at Frankfurt?](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/23696/do-i-require-airport-transit-visa-at-frankfurt)

Comment: In short, as you are an Indian citizen, you will need an airport transit visa. I let you look at the first answer to this question for more details.

Comment: @Vince I don't think it's true if the person has a Romanian visa.

Comment: @Annoyed you think there are different rules for Romanian visa holders? I was not sure. Then it should not be closed indeed if this is the case.

Comment: @Vince Just noticed that it's mentioned in Doc's answer to the previous question.

Answer (score 6):

My understanding is that you don't need a visa. The reasoning is the following:

- Generally speaking, airside non-Schengen transit in Munich (or other airports with an international transit area) does not require a Schengen visa as long as you don't want to enter the Schengen area.
- As an exception, the citizens from some countries (originally listed in annex IV to the Schengen agreement) do need an “airport transit visa” (ATV), even if they don't want to enter the Schengen area. India is *not* on that list so this ATV is not required everywhere in the Schengen area but can still be required in specific country. Germany *does* require Indian citizens to have an ATV so you can't generally transit there without a visa.
- As an exception to the exception, people who would otherwise require an ATV are exempted from the requirement if they have (or return after using) a visa from some non-Schengen countries including the US and, most importantly for this question, Romania (or, in fact, any EU/EEA member).

If you read carefully, all these rules are detailed in the [relevant Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_policies_in_the_European_Union). The [German embassy in London also confirms this](http://www.london.diplo.de/Vertretung/london/en/07/03__Visa/014__Airport__transit.html). In any case, if that's possible, it's always best to have the airline confirm it as they have to check that you have the right to transit in Germany before allowing you to board the plane in India.