# Transit visa requirement for Kenya citizen going trough Switzerland to US

Tags: schengen, transit, switzerland, kenyan-citizens

I am Kenyan going to U.S do I need transit visa in Switzerland?

Comment: You might find some of the details contained in answers to http://travel.stackexchange.com/q/19137/1820 helpful

Answer (score 0):

If you want to exit the airport and look around, then you will need a visa. If you remain in the transit area, then you will not need a visa if you are at the airport for less than 48 hours.

Source: http://www.visaswitzerland.co.uk/VisaSwitzerlandTransit.php